# How to escape special characters in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have the following string that I'm trying to convert to UTF-8:

```
Naïve file
```

I tried to convert it using Oracle:

```
UTL_URL.ESCAPE('Naïve file')
```

This returns `Na%EFve%20file`.

According to this [converter](https://www.urlencoder.org/), the result should be: `Na%C3%AFve%20file`, which is what I'm expecting.

How can I fix that?

Comment: "I'm trying to convert to UTF-8" is not what you try to do. What is your database character set?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit my database character set is AL32UTF8. Do you have any idea please ?

Comment: Default character set is `ISO-8859-1`, try `UTL_URL.ESCAPE('Naïve file', TRUE, 'UTF-8')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default character in `UTL_URL.ESCAPE` set is `ISO-8859-1`.

Try `UTL_URL.ESCAPE('Naïve file', TRUE, 'UTF-8')`